# Qt doing get request to YouTube api , doesn't support utf8 characters

Tags: c++, qt, https, youtube-api

Im doing simple get request with Qt , but the returend response is in gibrich , the part which isn't english . 
when i invoke the same request via browser every thing is fine and i get the right response 
what im missing here ? 
here is the code and the YouTube Api call.
the API :
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/cDholGGVc1M?v=2&alt=jsonc ( or json)

this is how i invoke it in Qt

```
 QUrl getUrl("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/cDholGGVc1M?v=2&alt=jsonc");
     QNetworkRequest request;
     request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT.toUtf8());
     request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
     request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
     request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
     request.setRawHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
     request.setUrl(getUrl);
     QEventLoop loop;
     //This tell the request only to cuntinue after all response is done
     QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager->get(request);
     connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
     loop.exec();       
     //return response 
     QByteArray data=reply->readAll();
     ApiResponse.append(data); // HERE IS ALL GIBRISH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encoding problem. Use this to get a UTF-8 representation of Gibrich:

```
ApiResponse.append(QString::fromUtf8(data));
```

rather than taking data directly into your ApiResponse.